# Constraining an argument to be an Int

Tags: haskell, constraints

I'm trying to declare a function where the numerical argument can only be an `Int`.

I'm writing a function that'll discard every `n`th element of a list. I'm using modulo arithmetic, but the `mod` function will only take a type of `Int` and I can't figure out how to guarantee my number will satisfy that.

My code is as follows:

```
dropEvery :: (Num n, Eq n) => n -> [a] -> [a]
dropEvery m list = [list !! i | i <- [1 .. length list], i `rem` m /= 0]
```

I've run `:info mod` and replaced `Num n` with `Real n, Enum n and Integral n` (all the constraints I can see in the output) but this still doesn't guarantee the compiler that `n` will be an `Int`.

I'm sure there are solutions to this problem which don't use such a imperative approach, but I'd like to use this opportunity to learn a bit more about how types and constraints work in Haskell by solving this problem head-on.

Comment: Why don't you define it as `Int -> [a] -> [a]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to use the actual type `Int` instead of using constrains `(Num n, Eq n)`. (Note that Haskell uses 0-based list indexing so I had to add a `-1` for it to work correctly.)

```hs
dropEvery :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
dropEvery m list = [list !! (i-1) | i <- [1 .. length list], i `rem` m /= 0]

main = print $ dropEvery 3 [1..20]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P6Uov8C1LLWoUsHKSsEzr0RB104hOjEWSnEhpHMVcjKLSxRsFaLBtKKigkamrqGmQo1CpoKNrkK0oYKenkJOal56SQZYZawOUCKhKDU3AahV31bBIJaLKzcxMw9oQkFRJtAiFQWE4cZA/Xp6Rgax//8DAA)

If you want to avoid the `!!` you can also avoid explicitly finding the length of the list by using `zip` which replaces your list comprehension with

```hs
[ l | (l,i) <- zip list [0..], (i+1) `rem` m /= 0]
```

Comment: If you really, really want the signature to seem polymorphic, but want to constraint `n` to being `Int`, use `~`: `dropEvery :: (n ~ Int) => ...`. (Needs `LANGUAGE GADTs`. extension.)

Comment: Um.  Why zip with `[0..]` then add 1 instead of just zipping with `[1..]`?

Comment: @Carl I wanted to emphasize that the list indices are 0-based even if it doesn't matter in this example. But maybe you're interested in [PPCG.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)? :)

Comment: Not interested in code golf at all. I'm interested in clarity and directness. If you want to associate the number 1 with a value, associate 1 with the value. Don't associate 0 with it and then add 1 when it's used. It's just extra complexity.